# how to call a js script from a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a site for fun and I wanted to open different pages based on what the user submites through a form.
The function which should do the job is "hotelSelection" but it doesn't work.

The autocomplete function properly works.

Thanks for the help!

```js
hotelSelection = function() 
{
  var hotelName = document.getElementById("hotelName").value;

    switch (hotelName) {
      case Mare Hotel:  
        window.open("liveItMareHotel.html");
        break;
      case Hotel 2:
        window.open("liveItHotel2.html");
        break;
      case Hotel 3:
        window.open("liveitHotel3.html");
        break;
      case Hotel 4:
        window.open("liveItHotel4.html");
        break;
      case Hotel 5:
        window.open("liveItHotel5.html");
        break;
        default:
        window.open("liveItDefaultList.html");
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="autoForm" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="hotelName" placeholder="Hotel Name">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="hotelSelection()">
</form>
```

Comment: `case "Mare Hotel":`, you need to use strings. That's why your getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", it's looking for 2 variables `Mare` and `Hotel` that don't exist, etc.

Comment: thank you Liam, we studied how to web code in high school 2 years ago and I didn't remember this :)

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it is a bad practise. You should do the redirection in the php file and call it from the form. Anyway with javascript the following code works.

**Html:**

```
<form id="autoForm"  autocomplete="off">
    <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
      <input type="text" name="hotelName" id="hotelName" placeholder="Hotel Name">
    </div>
  </form>
  <button onclick="hotelSelection()">Send</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function hotelSelection() {
    var hotelName = document.getElementById("hotelName").value;

      switch (hotelName) {
      case 'Mare Hotel':
        window.open("liveItMareHotel.html");
        break;
      case 'Hotel 2':
        window.open("liveItHotel2.html");
        break;
      case 'Hotel 3':
        window.open("liveitHotel3.html");
        break;
      case 'Hotel 4':
        window.open("liveItHotel4.html");
        break;
      case 'Hotel 5':
        window.open("liveItHotel5.html");
        break;
        default:
        window.open("liveItDefaultList.html");

  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the corrected code. Can you explain more about your suggestion? I've never used php anyway.

Comment: I learnt how to code at a scientific high school here in Italy, but never of very sophisticated. so, I'm very glad to you for every tips  you have :)

Comment: If my answer help you indeed, please accept it as an answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Here is working jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/bpvrf45w/

Try this

```
hotelSelection = function() 
{
  var hotelName = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

    switch (hotelName) {
      case 'Mare Hotel':  
        window.open("liveItMareHotel.html");
        break;
      case 'Hotel 2':
        window.open("liveItHotel2.html");
        break;
      case 'Hotel 3':
        window.open("liveitHotel3.html");
        break;
      case 'Hotel 4':
        window.open("liveItHotel4.html");
        break;
      case 'Hotel 5':
        window.open("liveItHotel5.html");
        break;
        default:
        window.open("liveItDefaultList.html");
    }
<form id="autoForm" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="hotelName" placeholder="Hotel Name">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="hotelSelection()">
</form>

<script src="js/hotelSelection.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can the downvoter explain why? I have also given working jsfiddle.

Comment: thank you a lot! I've never used sOverflow and I'm very impressed of your help guys ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
hotelSelection = function()
{
var hotelName = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    switch (hotelName) {
  case 'Mare Hotel':
    window.open("liveItMareHotel.html");
    break;
  case 'Hotel 2':
    window.open("liveItHotel2.html");
    break;
  case 'Hotel 3':
    window.open("liveitHotel3.html");
    break;
  case 'Hotel 4':
    window.open("liveItHotel4.html");
    break;
  case 'Hotel 5':
    window.open("liveItHotel5.html");
    break;
    default:
    window.open("liveItDefaultList.html");
}
}
</script>
```

Form like this

```
<form id="autoForm" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
        <input id="myInput" type="text" name="hotelName" placeholder="Hotel Name">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="hotelSelection()">
    </form>
```